# using autoForm/quickForm, returns Objects instead of an html form

Tags: meteor-autoform

I'm trying to use quickForm form autoForm to generate a form from my collection

```
<template name="NewRecipe">
    <div class="new-recipe-container">
        {{> quickForm collection="Recipes" id="insertRecipeForm" type="insert" class="new-recipe-form"}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Instead of displaying a simple table with labels and input fields and a submit button what it returns is an array of objects, they appear as

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
Submit
```

The button renders as a button, but the fields on my schema are not.

Comment: Therevwas a issue files, and the resolution was to rollback to version 1.4

Comment: But there are still errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to an older version, current version is 1.5.0. Need to use 1.4.3.

Here's the command:

```
cd [to your project]
meteor npm install --save simpl-schema@1.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall older simpl-schema

meteor npm uninstall --save simpl-schema

then downgrade simpl-schema 1.5.0 to 1.4.0

meteor npm install --save simpl-schema@1.4.3

It works for me.